# Search algorithm on sequential data model

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search

For sequential data models like `LinkedList`, search algorithms like `linear-search` and `binary-search` are well known.

Are their any other search algorithms apart from these two, that work on sequential data models like `LinkedList`?

*Note: As far as representation is concerned `tree` can also be a sequential data model(using python: `[[4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 9], 7]`) but that is not relevant to this question.*

Comment: If a tree can be a sequential model, then so can any other search data structure such as a hash table, skip list, radix or trie.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Tree is a  sequential data model from representation perspective, but array and linked list actually are sequential in nature. In tree you have breadth and depth.

Comment: linear-search and binary-search are just algorithms that are laid over the top of an array or linked list.  You can do the same with any other search algorithm/data structure.  Your linked list nodes can also be in a hashtable, for example.

Comment: Arrays are **not** sequential data models. They're random-access, and this is crucial to the fact that certain algorithms have the run-time they have. There's a world of difference between algorithms that require random access and those that don't, so it makes little sense to ask "What search methods are there for arrays or linked lists?"

Comment: @KilianFoth I edited question

Comment: Binary search does *not* work (well) on linked lists.

Comment: @Raphael yes finding mid element is costlier in linkedlist